# Consistent hashing collisions?

Tags: hash, distributed-system, consistent-hashing

Probably an implementation detail of consistent hashing, IIUC, under ideal conditions, with **N servers** and **K hash functions**, we could expect to see NK evenly distributed nodes on the hash ring.

but what if the hash of my servers collide with each other?

1. ignore them? probably won't work? in the extreme case, all K hashes of my server could be overshadowed by others?
2. some sort of collision resolution? with my limited hashtable knowledge, it has to be some kind of [OpenAddressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing)?

Comment: Consider rendezvous hashing instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing

Comment: thanks! looks like [rendez vous hashing](https://randorithms.com/2020/12/26/rendezvous-hashing.html) has no collision, huh? Although it's a bit off topic, I am seeking more insights into the consistent hashing implementation

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?